# Need To Get NSObject From DidSelectRow

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a calendar in my view that is loaded with the following fetch code:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Object" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:entity];
    [request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
    [request setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];
    [request setPropertiesToFetch :[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"timeStamp"]];

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *objects = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    NSArray *tempData = [objects valueForKey:@"timeStamp"];

    NSMutableArray * data1 = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSCalendar * gregorian = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
    [gregorian setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
    NSUInteger flags = ( NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit );
    NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"];
    [formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];

    [tempData enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        NSDate * date = [gregorian dateFromComponents:[gregorian components:flags fromDate:obj]];
        [data1 addObject:[formatter stringFromDate:date]];
    }];
    self.data = data1;
```

When I select a date in the calendar, I have the following code that will push to the next detail view

```
- (void)calendarMonthView:(TKCalendarMonthView *)monthView didSelectDate:(NSDate *)d { 
// Assuming `data` is from the code above & the date is in `00:00:00 +0000` form.

NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];

NSString * dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:d];

if ( [data containsObject:dateString] ) {
    // Push object to detail view??
}
```

}

My question is, how can I get the Object back that was fetched for which the timeStamp property is the date selected?  I want to get push the Object to the next view for which the timeStamp property is the date I selected from the calendar, which is loaded from an array of the fetch request I posted above.

Comment: Are you sure there is only single object for each date?

Comment: Yah, there is only 1 object for a date.  I made it so 2 objects CANNOT have the same timeStamp.

Comment: What about `2011-06-26 09:51:00 ..` and `2011-06-26 09:50:00 ..`?  They are not the same `timeStamp` right?

Comment: No, there is only one object per day.  so for 2011-06-26, there is only 1 object, regardless of time and minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use an `NSPredicate` instance to get the particular data. You will need to add this in `if` clause above,

```
if ( [data containsObject:dateString] ) {
    NSDate * searchDate = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];
    NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@" timeStamp == %@ ", searchDate];

    /* Create a fetch request with the predicate above and get the results from the MOC */
}
```